# Rails 4: how to find all rows where a certain attribute equals a certain value and change that value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, relational-database, rails-activerecord

In our Rails 4 app, there are four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :calendar
end
```

Here are the corresponding migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :total_calendar_count
      t.integer :owned_calendar_count

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateAdministrations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :administrations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :role

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
        t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
        t.date :date
        t.time :time
        t.string :focus
        t.string :format
        t.string :blog_title
        t.text :long_copy
        t.text :short_copy
        t.string :link
        t.string :hashtag
        t.string :media
        t.float :promotion
        t.string :target
        t.integer :approval
        t.text :comment

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Within the app, we offer the opportunity to users to quit a calendar they belong to, and to do so, we `destroy` the administration row in the join table that ties the given user to the given calendar.

When that happens, we want to do a couple of things:

- Check if there are other users belonging to this calendar
- If there are some, we want to `update` the value to their `administration.role`
- If there aren't any, we want to `destroy` the entire `calendar`

We believe this would happen in four parts:

1. In the `Adminstration` table, find all the `@administration` instances where
   `calendar_id` equals `calendar.id` and store all the fetched rows into a
   variable, for example `@administrations`
2. Check whether `@administrations` is true
3. If `@administrations` is nil, destroy `@administration.calendar`
4. If `@administrations` is true, change `@administration.role` for each `@administration` instance in `@administrations`

We know how to perform 2 with a simple operator, 3 with the `calendars#destroy` action we already have and 4 with a block, but we don't know how to code 1.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in an `after_destroy` callback within the `Administration` model.

```
class Administration
  # existing relationships / methods

  # new code
  after_destroy :your_stuff

  private

  def your_stuff # pick a more suitable method name
    cal = self.calendar
    other_admins = cal.administrators.where("id != ?", self.id)

    if other_admins.exists?
      new_role_value = "Something"
      other_admins.update_all(role: new_role_value)
      # ^ or iterate through all admins in case logic is more complicated
    elsif Calendar.exists?(id: cal.id)
      cal.destroy 
    end
  end
end
```

I hope that the code is self-explanatory.

I've added some precautions to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: It is self-explanatory, indeed. Thank you very much.

Comment: When we implement the code you suggest, we get the following error: `SystemStackError in CalendarsController#destroy stack level too deep`. Any idea why we get that? We saw in another thread that we may need to add `to_s` to `cal.administrators.where("user_id != ?", self.user_id)`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you had dependant relationships which ended up running the callback in an infinite loop when a calendar was destroyed. I've also made 1 other modification. Should help.

Comment: This seems to return a `SyntaxError in UsersController#show` error: `expecting ')'` and `expecting keyword_end` after `cal.destroy if Calendar.exists?(id: cal.id)` Should we use a tradition `if...end` statement instead?

Comment: I've changed it to `elsif` but it should've worked as is. Also check for typos.

Answer (score 1):

With this query:

```
@administration = Administration.joins(:calendar)
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I did not know we could call the `joins` method on a table.